# using syncadapter every 1 min need to send hit to server using Json get result

Tags: android, json, android-syncadapter

I am new to web services topic and same time new to syncadapter.

I read about syncadpter from developer site and other websites and get some idea and developed small app using it.

In that app using syncadapter every 1 min i display toast.It works.

Now i want to write web service call instead of toast and send hit every 1 min if there is any changes in data update it view in list.

I have trouble with integrating Json to my app.as i said i am new to this concept.i try to get some information from different websites still i am unable to get it.

There is no example for this.If any one knows plz post it.It will help me a lot.

Comment: As I understand, what you want to do is that your syncAdapter sends a call to a web server in order to check if the data in the server has changed and, in that case, update the data in your app. I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes 100% correct.u have any solution.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you to use Firebase Cloud Messaging platform: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ .  The server can send push notification to the device whenever there’s a change the client (so your app) needs to know about. After your app receive such  notification, it request a sync manually.

Comment: Thanks for that @ValentinoS.but i want to use syncadapter as per my requirement that hit will go constituency every 10 mins once if app is not in backgrond.thas y i want use syncadapter.

Comment: Maybe you are already using this, but I suggest you to take a look at addPeriodicSync method https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunPeriodic . To parse a JSON response from your server you can read a simple guide here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ . Hope this helps

Comment: I already working on those both but i am getting lot of errors.and i think iam missing somethig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search i found answer to my question.I am posting my answer which may be help others.

[Hear everything is explain clearly](https://github.com/ga-students/sync-adapters-lesson)

[Example github link](https://github.com/ga-students/sync-adapters-lab)

Using these links i implemented my answer which is work.I am posting this links may be it will help others.

Comment: links are dead now :( .  Next time please write the answer in here.